# AngularJS - Inject data to DOM with a constructor

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject data from a controller to the DOM. What is happening is that the only way i can pass data is whit a ng-click that will trigger an event to getBooks() function that is attached to the view by $scope.

But i want to see my info when i load the page and not by an event like click, i think i need some constructor or similar.

Controller

```
angular.module('helloWorldApp').controller('homeCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$log',
  function($scope,$http){
    $scope.getBooks = function(){
      $http.get('http://localhost:3010/api/books').then(function(resp){
        $scope.books = resp;
      });
    }
  }
])
```

View

```
<div class="home-page">
  {{books}}
</div>
```

Thanks for the Help

Comment: `function($scope,$http){` is a constructor. Just remove `$scope.getBooks = function(){` and `}` or call `$scope.getBooks()` there.

Comment: add  ng-init="getBooks()" in your div.

Comment: Thanks estus and Atiq, work with ng-init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
angular.module('helloWorldApp').controller('homeCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$log',
  function($scope,$http){

    function init() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:3010/api/books').then(function(resp){
                $scope.books = resp;
        });
    }

    init();
])
```

Use a function and call that function in controller

Comment: Have you got the answer ?

Comment: this is called self provoking function